# how to solve IVP using separable variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the question is:

> x dy/dx= 2y  ; y(0)=0

because when i solve this problem the integration constant 'c' gets zero... and i have to find its value in order to calculate a solution to given IVP

Comment: @ Sadia: Are you sure this question is stated correctly. Because the ODE yields a solution of zero.

Answer (score 2):

Solving this problem, I get
\begin{equation}
y = ax^2
\end{equation}
with $a$ a constant. Could you use this constant to find a solution for your IVP ?

**---UPDATE---**

I don't think this differential equation has a unique solution, if you check [this link](https://planetmath.org/picardstheorem) you see that
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = \frac{2y}{x}
\end{equation}
is not continuous in $(0,0)$, so Picard's Theorem doesn't hold.

Comment: i didn't get your point! please elaborate furthur...

Comment: sorry I forgot to enter side condition, I have edited my question please see it now...